# Doctrine 2 (Mitchell van Wijngaarden): Soft Deletes Still Show in Search Results

Tags: laravel-4, doctrine-orm, soft-delete

I am using Mitchell van Wijngaarden's Doctrine solution (https://github.com/mitchellvanw/laravel-doctrine/wiki/Soft-Deleting) with Laravel 4.

I have set up soft deleting but am still getting the soft-deleted entities showing up in search results. For example, the following query:

```
$group_instructions = $this->entityManager->getRepository('GroupInstruction')->findBy(array('librarian'=>$user));
```

This query returns all entities of the GroupInstruction class even if the "deleted_at" field has been filled with a timestamp. I was under the impression that all soft deleted items would be hidden. Has anybody had experience with this?

Answer (score -1):

In order to activate soft deletable, you need to enable it for EntityManager filters.
I am not sure how exactly this is done on laravel, but on doctrine this is done like this:

`$em->getFilters()->enable('soft-deletable');`

See more here:
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md#setup-and-autoloading

Comment: This is a completely different package.